# How to "zeroize" Rust BTreeMap securely

Tags: rust, memory, struct, btreemap

I want to use Rust's [zeroize](https://docs.rs/zeroize/latest/zeroize/) crate for zeroizing BTreeMap entries. But zeroize doesn't seems to provide an out-of-the-box implementation for BTreeMap.

Currently, I'm resorting to [clear](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.clear) to remove the map's entries.

Q1. How safe is it to use simply clear out my secrets stored in the map & without zeroizing them?

Q2. How can I use zeroize with `std::collection::BTreeMap`? I think I've to iterate over each element to zeroize it. An additional complexity with this approach is that my map contains **"complex" generic structs**. So will I have to zeroize turtle all the way down?

Q2.a) Any other crates that might help me with zeroizing BTreeMap like mine?

My struct eg:

```
let my_map1: BTreeMap<usize, MyStruct1<G1Projective>> = BTreeMap::new();

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct1<G: MyTrait1 + MyTrait2> {
  #[serde(serialize_with: .., deserialize_with: ..)]
  field1: G,

  #[serde(serialize_with: .., deserialize_with: ..)]
  field2: Vec<G>,
}
```

Comment: You can `zeroize` a mutable iterator, so any datastrcture that allows iterating over its elements (as a `BTreeMap` does) and which contains zeroizable members (that depends on `MyStruct1<G1Projective>` is very easy to zeroize.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to zeroize the whole hierarchy of structs that hold a field that holds a secret. You only need to implement `Zeroize` on the field itself. The easiest way to do that is to simply use the [`Zeroizing`](https://docs.rs/zeroize/latest/zeroize/#zeroizingz-wrapper-for-zeroizing-arbitrary-values-on-drop) wrapper, e.g.:

```
use zeroize::Zeroizing;

struct User {
    username: String,
    password: Zeroizing<String>,
};
```

Then the passwords will be cleared whenever a `User` is destroyed (including when you `clear` a `BTreeMap`, or even simply let it go out of scope).

Note however that simply storing any kind of secret in a `BTreeMap` is inherently insecure, because adding (or removing) items in the map may cause other items to be reallocated or moved and the original memory location will *not* be cleared in that case, only the final location when the map is cleared or dropped.

Comment: When you say that storing a secret in `BTreeMap` is not secure, does that include Zeroized secrets, or not? I'd expect not... but it's a bit confusing at the moment.

Comment: Yes that includes zeroized secrects, see https://docs.rs/zeroize/latest/zeroize/#stackheap-zeroing-notes What it says about `Vec` and `String` also applies to `BTreeMap`, except that for `BTreeMap` there is no equivalent to `reserve` or `with_capacity` to work around the issue.

Comment: To elaborate on what I just said, storing a `Zeroizing<String>` or `Zeroizing<Vec<_>>` in a `BTreeMap` should be fine because the `BTreeMap` doesn't hold the secret data itself, only a reference to it. However storing e.g. a `Zeroizing<[u8; 16]>` is insecure because then the secret data is held directly in the `BTreeMap`.

Comment: @Jmb Is storing `Zeroizing<SomeStruct<_>>` still safe when I'm **cloning** it?

Comment: @MatthieuM. What do you think about my cloning question in the comments?

Comment: @NewToCode: I have no idea, and it probably warrants a different question -- comments are meant to be removed.